# ffmpeg tpad adding delay to start and stop of film

Tags: ffmpeg

In ffmpeg there is the `-filter_complex "tpad=stop_duration=20"` that adds 20 seconds to back of video/stream, or `-filter_complex "tpad=start_duration=20"` which adds it to the front.

How can I add it to both? Something like `ffmpeg  -re -i {$file} -filter_complex "tpad=stop_duration=20&start_duration=20"` duration does not work, and there is no documentation I can find on using both filters in one command.

Comment: Multiple options for the same filter are separated by `:`

Comment: @Gyan that is the correct answer. If you write it will except.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple options for the same filter are separated by `:`, so it would be

```
tpad=stop_duration=20:start_duration=20
```